# My MacBook Pro upgrade OS X to macOS Sierra 2 times

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

Yesterday I upgraded OS X on my MacBook Pro (2015 early 8g 256g) to macOS Sierra, and Xcode (7.3.1) to Xcode (8.2.1).

**Attention** when upgrade the OS version, my macbook pro restart several times.

But today when I open my Xcode, it says:

[image]

**Translate**

> "Xcode" is updating
>   "Xcode" is updating, can not open it.

But my Xcode is not usable, and App Store showed I should upgrade the OS version, as if 10.12.2 to 10.12.2. So I upgraded my OS X second time, and my MacBook Pro restarted several times too.

I have some questions:

1. Are there any issues with my MacBook Pro?
2. When upgrading system version, my Pro restarted several times, is it normal?

Comment: Most of us probably can't read that error message - would you like to translate it?

Comment: @Tetsujin, i have translated it.